# add item to become first item in an object

Tags: jquery, arrays, angularjs, object, push

I would like add 
      {title:Jessicas',author:'JK', url:"images/beach.jpg"} to become the first object in the book array.

However when I use push the information, it will become the last item in books.

```
if ($('#form').valid()){   
     $scope.books.push(
     {
            title: 'Jessicas',
            author: 'JK',
            url: "images/beach.jpg"
     }) 
}

/*  Create JSON representations of the content */ 
$scope.books=[
      {title:'Jani',author:'Norway', url:"images/beach.jpg"},
      {title:'Hege',author:'Sweden',url:"images/plane.jpg"}
];
```

Comment: Use array [unshift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `unshift` method to prepend an element to the beginning of an array.

> **`Array.prototype.unshift()`**
>   The unshift() method adds one or more elements to the beginning of an array and returns the new length of the array.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift

---

In a similar fashion, or rather opposite :) You might also want to use the opposite of the array retrieval method. Where usually you would use `pop` to get the last element of the array (ie: first one that was inserted), you can use [`shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) to access the last element in the array (ie: the most recently added).

Answer (score 1):

you can use `unshift` array method to insert at first index in the list of arrays .

```
$scope.books.unshift({"title:'stackoverflow',author:'stack', url:"images/stack.jpg""})
```

which will insert the object to the first index (position) of the array